# Jest changed test directory resulting beforeAll is not defined

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I used to put all my tests together inside of `__test__` directory. But I decided to put each test files into each component's directory with different name convention.

Old Structure:

```
src/
 __test__/
  example.test.js
  example2.test.js
```

New Structure:

```
src/
 components/
  example/
   example-controller.js
   example-model.js
   example-route.js
   example-test.js
```

As naming and location of a directory changed, I updated all import statement and namings for according files. I was using default feature of Jest but since I changed test file name to **example-test** from **example.test** I also updated package.json

```
"jest": {
          "testRegex": "./src/components/*/.*.-test.js$"
 },
```

Problem is when I run the project, npm run it throws

> beforeAll((0, _asyncToGenerator3.default)( /*#**PURE***/_regenerator2.default.mark(function _callee() {
>
> ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined

any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [regextester](https://www.regextester.com/) with your file-paths before getting frustrated. Also, look at some popular existing javascript projects using jest and check their jest configurations to see how the community is settling on project structure. It may seem simple to follow others, but most software engineers don't work alone, and usually agree on good practices.

Consider coming back to this project in a year; You are changing the default behavior of a simple process that works beautifully out of the box. Someone may hate you later after a `git blame`.

If all you want to do is check all `-test.js` files, slowly modify the [default config](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string-array-string) until you match the file paths you want.

```
(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$
```

Should probably (for you) be:

```
(.*/src/.*(-test).jsx?)
```